# Installing Ubuntu in Virtual Box ruins my internet connection on Windows 10 computer

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox, dns

After installing Ubuntu in Virtual Box on my W10 box, my internet connection won't stay up for an hour even when neither the VB manager nor Ubuntu is running.

Diagnostics: "DNS server isn't responding." What could cause a DNS server to stop responding? That's all they do is respond. Sometimes disabling then re-enabling the adapter works - mostly not. How can I prevent VB from interfering with my internet service. I thought VM's were supposed to protect the host from damage.

Sometimes, bringing up Gmail in Chrome attempts to "reconnect" successfully.

Comment: Have you tried messing with the different adapter types?  If it's nat, switch to bridged.. if its bridged, switch to nat.  See if the problem goes away.

Comment: Virtual Box (or VMware) installs part of itself in the network section of your host computer. Shut off your guest machines, and run a TCP/IP Reset , DNS Flush.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer  and test your internet again with Virtual Box running

Answer (score 0):

Then you should consider trying to disable the VirtualBox virtual network adapters. Go to Settings > Network and Security > Status > Change adapter options. Now right click each VBox adapter and click Disable. Then obtain a new DHCP lease (`ipconfig /release && ipconfig /renew` in Command Prompt) and flush the DNS cache (`ipconfig /flushdns`). Disable static TCP/IP settings in your network adapter (ethernet and wireless) and assign static settings to VBox network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Box (or VMware) installs part of itself in the network section of your host computer.

Shut off your guest machines, and run a TCP/IP Reset , DNS Flush for the physical adapter on the host machine.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

Then: ipconfig /flushdns

Then: restart the computer and test your internet again with Virtual Box running . This will likely fix your issue.

I had posted first as a comment and did some further testing so I post now as an answer.

Comment: I tried this ... my Inet has been up for 3-1/2 hours.. Thanks, Bill Drissel

Comment: Hopefully it will stay up now.

Answer (score 0):

My host is MacOS,  I was experiencing similar issues.  DNS on my LAN started failing on any device attached to my router.  For my case I think part of it is my ISP intercepting DNS lookups.   I moved everything to DNS over TLS.

```
#!/bin/bash
# static IP - DNS servers and don't use gateway for DNS
# https://netplan.io/examples
# https://netplan.io/reference
sudo cp $HOME/mediacentre/bin/01-netcfg.yaml /etc/netplan/.
sudo netplan apply
# DNS over TLS
# https://www.internetsociety.org/blog/2018/12/dns-privacy-in-linux-systemd/
sudo cp $HOME/mediacentre/bin/resolved.conf /etc/systemd/.
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
# test it...
resolvectl query bbc.co.uk

# install stubby to do DNS over TLS
sudo apt-get install -y stubby
# use patched stubby config
sudo cp $HOME/mediacentre/bin/stubby.yml /etc/stubby/.
sudo systemctl restart stubby
```

**01-netcfg.yaml**

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.202/24
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      dhcp6: true
      dhcp6-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
```

**resolved.conf**

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8
#FallbackDNS=
Domains=~.
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
DNSOverTLS=opportunistic
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

**stubby.yml** use Google DNS over TLS,  incomplete YaML file.

```
## Google
  - address_data: 8.8.8.8
    tls_auth_name: "dns.google"
  - address_data: 8.8.4.4
    tls_auth_name: "dns.google"
```